# parse a special xml in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, shell

I have s special xml file like below:

```
<alarm-dictionary source="DDD" type="ProxyComponent">

    <alarm code="402" severity="Alarm" name="DDM_Alarm_402">
    <message>Database memory usage low threshold crossed</message>
    <description>dnKinds = database
    type = quality_of_service
    perceived_severity = minor
    probable_cause = thresholdCrossed
    additional_text = Database memory usage low threshold crossed
    </description>
    </alarm>

        ...
</alarm-dictionary>
```

I know in python, I can get the "alarm code", "severity" in tag **alarm** by:

```
for alarm_tag in dom.getElementsByTagName('alarm'):
    if alarm_tag.hasAttribute('code'):
        alarmcode = str(alarm_tag.getAttribute('code'))
```

And I can get the text in tag **message** like below:

```
for messages_tag in dom.getElementsByTagName('message'):
    messages = ""
    for message_tag in messages_tag.childNodes:
        if message_tag.nodeType in (message_tag.TEXT_NODE, message_tag.CDATA_SECTION_NODE):
            messages += message_tag.data
```

But I also want to get the **value** like **dnkind**(database), **type**(quality_of_service), **perceived_severity**(thresholdCrossed) and **probable_cause**(Database memory usage low threshold crossed
) in tag **description**.

**That is, I also want to parse the content in the tag in xml.**

Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the text from the `description` tag, it's nothing to do with XML parsing. You just need do simple string-parsing to get the `type = quality_of_service` keys/values strings into something nicer to use in Python like a dictionary

With some slightly simpler parsing thanks to [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), it would look like this

```
messages = """
<alarm-dictionary source="DDD" type="ProxyComponent">

    <alarm code="402" severity="Alarm" name="DDM_Alarm_402">
    <message>Database memory usage low threshold crossed</message>
    <description>dnKinds = database
    type = quality_of_service
    perceived_severity = minor
    probable_cause = thresholdCrossed
    additional_text = Database memory usage low threshold crossed
    </description>
    </alarm>

        ...
</alarm-dictionary>
"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Parse XML
tree = ET.fromstring(messages)

for alarm in tree.getchildren():
    # Get code and severity
    print alarm.get("code")
    print alarm.get("severity")

    # Grab description text
    descr = alarm.find("description").text

    # Parse "thing=other" into dict like {'thing': 'other'}
    info = {}
    for dl in descr.splitlines():
        if len(dl.strip()) > 0:
            key, _, value = dl.partition("=")
            info[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    print info
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure on Python, but after quick research.

Seeing as you can already get all of the content from the description tag in XML, can you not split by line breaks, and then split each line using the str.split() function on the equals signs to give you name / value separately?

e.g.

```
for messages_tag in dom.getElementsByTagName('message'):
messages = ""
for message_tag in messages_tag.childNodes:
    if message_tag.nodeType in (message_tag.TEXT_NODE, message_tag.CDATA_SECTION_NODE):
        messages += message_tag.data
tag =  str.split('=');
tagName = tag[0]
tagValue = tag[1]
```

(I haven't taken into account splitting each line up and looping)

But that should get you on the right track :)

Comment: Not valid Python, but that's definitely the way to solve the problem - unless the description was something like `<info key="dnKinds">database</info>`, it's not an XML problem

Comment: Hehe, I had a feeling it wasn't but Python isn't my speciality (Haven't used it in a few years) so I just quickly perused the Python docs to provide an answer with some sort of good logic at least.

Comment: @ldiot211, Thanks a lot! yes, I think your solution definitely solve the problem!

Comment: Glad to have been able to help sir!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no library to handle the text as `DOM` elements.

You can however (after you have the message in the `message` variable) do:

```
description = {}
messageParts = message.split("\n")
for part in messageParts:
    descInfo = part.split("=")
    description[descInfo[0].strip()] = descInfo[1].strip()
```

then you'll have inside `description` the information you need in the form of a `key-value` map.

You should also add error handling on my code...